# Optimization in R with stochastic objective function and an equality constraint

Tags: r, statistics, mathematical-optimization

I am looking for an R package/function that will help me find optimal values of 4 parameters. Specifically, I am trying to model a known empirical distribution (the US household income distribution, Y) as the sum of the two log-normal random variables (that is, Y=E+L where ln(E)~N(μ<sub>E</sub>,σ<sub>E</sub><sup>2</sup>) and ln(L)~N(μ<sub>L</sub>,σ<sub>L</sub><sup>2</sup>). Therefore I have 4 parameters to optimize over. For the objective function, I wish to use the Kolmogorov-Smirnov statistic to measure the difference between the simulated distribution using these 4 parameters, and the actual distribution, which I have stored as a vector. I also have an equality constraint for the optimization, that the expected value of L is in a proportion 0<θ<1 of the total expected value of Y.

So far I have tried both the `nloptr` packages and the `alabama` package, and neither have succeeded. Here is what my objective function and constraint function look like, first the objective function:

```
compare_distributions <- function(x, ref_dist, ...) {
  mu_E <- x[1]
  sigma_E <- x[2]
  mu_L <- x[3]
  sigma_L <- x[4]
  E <- rlnorm(n = 100000, meanlog = mu_E, sdlog = sigma_E)
  L <- rlnorm(n = 100000, meanlog = mu_L, sdlog = sigma_L)
  Y <- E + L
  return(unname(ks.test(Y, ref_dist)$statistic))
}
```

Here you can see I am generating 100,000 draws of the simulated random distribution, and then using the `ks.test` function to calculate the statistic comparing its similarity to the reference distribution. Then, the constraint function:

```
opt_constraint <- function(x, theta, ...) {
  mu_E <- x[1]
  sigma_E <- x[2]
  mu_L <- x[3]
  sigma_L <- x[4]
  return(mu_L + sigma_L^2/2 - mu_E - sigma_E^2/2 - log(theta / (1- theta)))
}
```

Here the returned expression is equal to 0 when the optimization constraint regarding the ratio of the means of the log-normal distributions is satisfied.

When I feed these expressions into alabama, I receive a cryptic error message (noting that `household_income` is the vector containing the known distribution of household income):

```
alabama(par = c(0, 1, 0, 1),
       fn = compare_distributions,
       heq = opt_constraint,
       ref_dist = household_income,
       theta = 0.5)
```

Yields:

```
Error in alabama(par = c(0, 1, 0, 1), fn = compare_distributions, heq = opt_constraint,  : 
  promise already under evaluation: recursive default argument reference or earlier problems?
```

I do not see where I have done anything recursive here, and looking around this forum and others for help with this error message did not reveal anything useful.

I am thinking that perhaps `nloptr` and `alabama` are just not suited to the sort of objective function I am trying to optimize over, given the random nature of it. Are there any packages that would achieve what I am looking for?

Comment: Can you give us an example of what household_income looks like? It is helpful to have a reproducible example to give an answer.

Comment: The actual value is a very large numeric vector, so I can't copy and paste it here. `household_income <- rlnorm(100000, 3, 1)` or something similar ought to work for illustration purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to minimize your function with the following code :

```
library(DEoptim)
library(RSolnp)

objective_Function <- function(param, ref_dist, theta)
{
  mu_E <- param[1]
  sigma_E <- param[2]
  mu_L <- param[3]
  sigma_L <- param[4]
  set.seed(1234)
  E <- rlnorm(n = 100000, meanlog = mu_E, sdlog = sigma_E)
  L <- rlnorm(n = 100000, meanlog = mu_L, sdlog = sigma_L)
  Y <- E + L
  term1 <- unname(ks.test(Y, ref_dist)$statistic)
  term2 <- mu_L + sigma_L ^ 2 / 2 - mu_E - sigma_E ^ 2 / 2 - log(theta / (1 - theta))
  term2 <- exp(term2) - 1
  val <- term1 + 100 * term2 ^ 2
  return(val)    
}

opt_constraint <- function(x) 
{
  theta <- 0.5
  mu_E <- x[1]
  sigma_E <- max(x[2], 0)
  mu_L <- x[3]
  sigma_L <- max(x[4], 0)
  val <- mu_L + sigma_L ^ 2 / 2 - mu_E - sigma_E ^ 2 / 2 - log(theta / (1 - theta))
  return(val)
}

compare_distributions <- function(x) 
{
  ref_dist <- household_income
  mu_E <- x[1]
  sigma_E <- max(x[2], 0)
  mu_L <- x[3]
  sigma_L <- max(x[4], 0)
  set.seed(1234)
  E <- rlnorm(n = 100000, meanlog = mu_E, sdlog = sigma_E)
  L <- rlnorm(n = 100000, meanlog = mu_L, sdlog = sigma_L)
  Y <- E + L
  return(unname(ks.test(Y, ref_dist)$statistic))
}

set.seed(12435)
household_income <- rlnorm(100000, 3, 1)
list_Obj_Res <- list()

obj_DEoptim <- DEoptim(fn = objective_Function, lower = c(-4, 0, -4, 0), upper = rep(7, 4),
                       ref_dist = household_income, theta = 0.5,
                       control = list(itermax = 200, parallelType = 1))

list_Obj_Res[[1]] <- list(par = obj_DEoptim$optim$bestmem,
                          value = obj_DEoptim$optim$bestval)

for(i in 2 : 10)
{
  print(i)
  
  if(i %% 2 == 1)
  {
    obj_Optim <- optim(fn = objective_Function, par = list_Obj_Res[[i - 1]]$par,
                       ref_dist = household_income, theta = 0.5)
    
    list_Obj_Res[[i]] <- list(par = obj_Optim$par, value =  obj_Optim$value)
    
  }else 
  {
    obj_RSolnp <- solnp(pars = list_Obj_Res[[i - 1]]$par, 
                        fun = compare_distributions, 
                        eqfun = opt_constraint, eqB = 0)
    
    list_Obj_Res[[i]] <- list(par = obj_RSolnp$pars, value = obj_RSolnp$values)
    
  }
  
  print(list_Obj_Res[[i]])
}

opt_constraint(x = tail(list_Obj_Res, 1)[[1]]$par)
        par3 
1.110223e-16 

> compare_distributions(x = tail(list_Obj_Res, 1)[[1]]$par)
[1] 0.0047

> tail(list_Obj_Res, 1)[[1]]$par
    par1     par2     par3     par4 
2.016786 1.285449 1.947603 1.338188
```